# Run SHOW DBS command in MongoDB from a web application

Tags: mongodb, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I am new to Mongo and trying to develop a web application which executes some of the main commands of Mongo via a web app. 
I want to show all the databases available to the user on the first page. For this I need to run SHOW DBS via my application and retrieve the results so that i can populate them into the application as a listview.

I will further need to run SHOW COLLECTIONS if the user enters into any of the database.

I am using JavaEE programming. How can I do that?

Comment: Try this page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/, i.e. to answer: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/#dbcmd.listDatabases

Answer (score 0):

The *show* commands are shell functions and thus not directly available in the driver. You can use these methods instead:

- [MongoClient.getDatabaseNames()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/Mongo.html#getDatabaseNames--)
- [DB.getCollectionNames()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DB.html#getCollectionNames--)